# RAILS - SCOPE WITH 2 TABLES

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

RAILS - SCOPE FILTER THROUGH 2 TABLES

Hi, I'm new to Rails and I'm using Translate to post here.

I have the scenario below:
Ata_Public -> Ata_Object -> Products

How can I set up a filter to select all Ata_publics through the category_id inside Products?

```
         scope :filter_category, -> (params) {
           params[:category_id].present? ?
             joins(:ata_objects)
             .joins(:products)
             .where("ata_objects.products.category_id = ?", params[:category_id])
           :
             all
         }
```

I'm doing it this way, but I don't have the expected result.
What should my scope look like?

Relationships are right.

clarifying, inside the Ata_Public model, I'm creating this scope: filter_category, to pass the ID and list only the minutes that have the product with this category_id.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0I0s.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
scope :filter_category, -> (params) {
  joins(ata_objects: :products).where(
    products: { category_id: params[:category_id] }
  ) if params[:category_id].present?
}
```